# unit testing C function expecting SIGSEGV

Tags: c, testing, signals, glibc, segmentation-fault

I am trying to unit test C/glibc code that I know results in undefined behaviour, but will fail with SEGV given appropriate the compiler options. Something like:

```
void will_fail(char *bar) {
    bar[10000] = 'X';
}

void test_will_fail(void) {
    will_fail("foo");    // How can I handle this failing?
}
```

Is there a way to trap the next SEGV, possibly GCC specific or asm? If it needs a separate address space (fork/exec), what is a good way to tell that the spawned process ended with SEGV?

I am using c11 / x86-64 / glibc 2.26 / gcc 7.2.0 with -fsanitize=address / CUnit (which does not use a separate address space for unit tests). The only hard requirement is to stay in the realm of C.

Any guidance is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: C won't protect you unless you check the limits first. `if strlen(bar) > 10000) bar[10000] = 'X';`

Comment: You could use `assert` to trap it, or write a recovery strategy. Commercial code can't just fall over. It has to be robust.

Comment: SIGSEGV is a signal; you can set a signal handler for it. However, there isn't a reliable way to return from the handler; it should exit (probably with `_exit()`). Writing to a string literal will often provoke a SIGSEGV. You can use the exit status from a waited-for child process to spot that it died from a signal (and which signal) — see [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html). You could use the SA_SIGINFO option to [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) to get more information about what's up.

Comment: That's a good lead Jonathan, thanks.

Comment: Weathervane: Of course :) the contrived example is looking for a way to test that calling certain code will result in unexpected behaviour without the test succumbing to unexpected behaviour as well.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Why shouldn't there be a reliable way  to return? After returning, the process resumes execution with the instruction causing the signal and the same context (if it wasn't altered in the handler, of course). How is that unreliable?

Comment: @Ctx: POSIX [Signal Concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) specifies: _The behavior of a process is undefined after it returns normally from a signal-catching function for a SIGBUS, SIGFPE, SIGILL, or SIGSEGV signal that was not generated by `kill()`, `sigqueue()`, or `raise()`._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The context is clearly Linux on x86-64, where it is indeed no problem. Posix may say that it is unreliable because it wants to support many platforms where this may not be possible. But on the platform of the OP it works as I described above.

Comment: kinda new here. is there any way to promote Jonathen' s comment to an answer?